# Make Firefox cache a webpage so that I can view it without a reload after a restart

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I want Firefox to be able to cache webpages such that I can read the pages later after a restart. I've tried setting the cache size to 350MB but it still doesn't work as intended. Opera seems to do it without a single tweak. It can display an SO question even after closing and restarting it while Firefox demands a reload.

How do I make Firefox behave like Opera in this scenario? I'd hate to switch to Opera since it has a tendency to crash when I open many tabs, plus Firefox's addons are to die for.

Comment: Are you looking to view webpages offline or are you wanting the last webpage to be visible on Firefox startup?

Comment: Yes, view them when I'm offline without having to save them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Firefox profile manager to work offline.

In order to access the profile manager press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `firefox -p`

[image: firefox -p in the run dialog]

Then in the profile manager select `Work Offline`

[image: Firefox Profile Manager]

Click on `Start Firefox` and you will be able to browse your history offline.

Comment: That is really cool. Where do you learn such stuff? Can't believe it works.

Comment: I found this information here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_work-offline